# Run GitLab CI for a subdirectory in the same project

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have three subprojects (Angular and Node.js) in the same GitLab project. Now I want to create the `gitlab-ci.yml` file for building and deploying one of this subprojects. Can I create three different `gitlab-ci.yml` files and run them inside subdirectories? Is it possible? Or should I push those into three different projects?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My personal preference is to keep projects small. So I usually create one GitLab project per, e.g., module, library, program, design, etc.

But if you really wanted to, you could easily either:

- Create a single `.gitlab-ci.yml` that goes something like:

  ```
  my_job:
    stage: test
    script:
      - |
         cd "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/folder1"
         < do stuff >
         cd "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/folder2"
         < do stuff>
         ...
  ```
- Create multiple gitlab-ci configurations inside the folders and [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html) them in the root *.gitlab-ci.yml* file

  ```
  include:
    - 'folder1/pipeline.yml'
    - 'folder2/pipeline.yml'
  ```

Note that when using the second option, you will still have to `cd folderX` since pipelines always start in the repository's root directory, no matter from where they are imported.

Comment: Great touch with `include` feature!